# Accelerometer's equations

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have been going over Accelerometer's tutorial and some aspects still confusing to me:

> - values[0]: Acceleration minus Gx on the x-axis
> - values[1]: Acceleration minus Gy on the y-axis
> - values[2]: Acceleration minus Gz on the z-axis

The question is: when the device lies flat on a table **in its default orientation** 
it outputs *+9,81* instead of *-9.81*.

> If the device lies flat on table Z-axis points down - so the Gz is *9,81*
>       therefore values[2] shall be ( 0 - Gz) = (0 - 9,81) = -9,81.

The question is why is that ?
With X and Y axes there is no such confusion.

Comment: What is your question? The device is free to orient its coordinate system any which way it chooses. The Z-axis points downward, because that's how they decided to do it. What is the confusion?

Comment: values[2] should be -9,81 instead of 9,81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple (i.e. not rigorous and will have real physicists turning in their graves) is that the usual convention is that if the Z acceleration is negative the device is accelerating downwards i.e. in this case towards the centre of the earth.

Since it is staying still in a gravitational field it 'feels like' it is accelerating upwards (i.e. positive acceleration) just to stay in place.

(this is all explained pretty clearly in the SDK docs: [Using the Accelerometer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel)